# Why am I getting undefined when I console log imageUrl when its in there?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am wanting to render out images that users upload with their surveys.

I console logged `this.props.surveys` and clearly there is a property of `imageUrl` in it.

```
renderImage() {
  console.log(this.props.surveys);
}

// output:

0:
 body: "asdfg"
 imageUrl: 'bf0idba0inbdbnadbidfbn'
 no: 0
 subject: "another survey with image"
 title: "My Second Image Survey"
```

I expect it to render out the image from that `imageUrl` but instead it returns undefined when I `console.log(this.props.surveys.imageUrl);`

Comment: try printing out more. `console.table(this.props.surveys)`, `console.log(typeof this.props.surveys[0])`

Comment: @JohnRuddell, only index of 0 has the `imageUrl`, I am going to guess that is the problem? But have no idea what to do here. That was a feature I added today, all other surveys do not have `imageUrl`.

Comment: @JohnRuddell, also its a typeof `object`.

Comment: ok so i dont get what the issue is. when does it turn undefined? have you not loaded the data yet or something

Comment: @JohnRuddell, no I think I have to run `.map()` through `this.props.surveys` and then render out each property like `{survey.imageUrl}`, not sure how to put that together but I believe that is the issue.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.surveys)), what's the output?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
console.log(this.props.surveys[0].imageUrl);
```

Comment: I tried that and I still got undefined. It says it cannot read property imageUrl of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
renderSurvey() {
  return this.props.surveys.reverse().map((survey) => {
    return (
     <div className="card darken-1" key={survey._id}>
      <div className=""card-content">
     <img
        src={
          "https://my-bucket-123.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/" +
         survey.imageUrl
        }
        width="200"
        height="200"
     />
     <span className="card-title">{survey.title}</span>
     .....
    </div>
   </div>
  )
 });
}
```

And so on like that.